# How do I make this terminal alkyne into a methyl alkene on the third carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction, c-c-addition

How do I get from but-3-yn-1-ylbenzene to (3-methylbut-3-en-1-yl)benzene? I have tried $\ce{NaNH2}$ in $\ce{CH3Br}$ and then $\ce{H2}$ with a Lindlar catalyst, but that adds the methyl group at the other end of the double bond. How do I make the methyl group add to the third carbon instead?

[image: From but-3-yn-1-ylbenzene to (3-methylbut-3-en-1-yl)benzene, without reactants.]

Comment: Reacting it with LiCuMe2 followed by aqueous workup might work. The more obvious route is a mercury catalysed hydration and Wittig.

Comment: @EpichinoM2  is correct. What the question setter is expecting to see is oxymercuration to the methyl ketone followed by Wittig. Not a reaction that any H&S officer will let you do in a lab though.

Comment: @waylander: Health & Safety might object to oxymercuration of an alkene (stoichiometric) but certainly not with an alkyne (catalytic). They see "mercury" and panic.

Comment: @user55119  My use of Al/Hg amalgam as a reducing agent upset them greatly

Comment: @Waylander: I once tried to have H&S dispose of a diffusion pump containing mercury and wrapped in asbestos. Too complex a problem. I put the Hg in a separate container and that was a solvable situation.